# How to properly register a volume location to a Docker container for PHP 7?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am attempting to get a Docker container running PHP7, with a specific volume location and specific port `55211:80`

When I add the following code to my docker-compose.yml file and compose up, the process is successful.

```
 phpsandbox:
    container_name: php_sandbox
    restart: always
    image: php:7
    ports:
      - "55211:80"
    volumes:
      - ./phpsandbox:/var/www/html/
```

I can see that my volume directory exists with my index.php inside...But if I then go to `localhost:55211` in my browser, the browser says...

```
This page isn’t working localhost didn’t send any data.
```

What am I doing wrong in this part of my docker-compose.yml file?

**UPDATE**

From powershell, if I type in `docker ps -a` to see all running containers, php_sandbox is continosuly restarting, so I KNOW that something is wrong with this piece of code in my docker-compose.yml file, but don't know what...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `php:7` image only includes command line php tools. The image does not include a web server, so there is nothing on port 80 to respond to requests.

Try the [`php:7-apache`](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/php#with-apache) image which comes with a preconfigured Apache httpd 2 web server that should work with your compose config.

Comment: biiiinnnngo! Thanks Matt for helping me see what's going on behind the scenes!